# random.randit not working with int(input)

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on code that will roll dice with a specific number of sides. I want the user to be able to determine the number of sides. Here is my code so far:

```
import random

var=0
spaceors=''
d_input=('Die sides:')
d_count=('Die count:')
droll = random.randint(1, int(d_input))
```

Running this gives me the response:

```
'''droll = random.randint(1, int(d_input))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Die sides:''''
```

What issues are there? How do I make a random number generator with an `int(input)` use?

Answer (score 0):

Your code was setting the variable d_input equal to the string 'Die sides:' and then trying to convert that string into an int, because you did not use the "input" function which solicits console-based input from the user.

Try:

```
import random

var=0
spaceors=''
d_input=input('Die sides:')
d_count=input('Die count:')
droll = random.randint(1, int(d_input))
```

... instead.

Answer (score 0):

Close the “die_sides” and the “d_count” with the input() function. Or else you’re just passing those variables as normal strings that the user can’t give input to. This causes python to try to convert literally the strings of die_sides and die_count to integers.